# Can't understand this behaviour of strtok and sscanf

Tags: c, strtok, scanf

I want to split a string on "\n", parse the token, and store some values in a struct.

Here's the actual code:

```
typedef struct {
    char *address;
    int port;
    unsigned int nodeId;
} node;

...

node *ft = malloc(32 * sizeof(node));

...

int function (char *addr, int port, node * ft) {
    char request[BUFSIZE], answer[8192];
    char *token;
    int c = 0;

    snprintf(request, sizeof(request), "Keyword");
    request(addr, port, request, answer);

    printf("answer at this point is:\n%s\n", answer);
    memset(&token, '\0', sizeof(token));

    token = strtok(answer, "\n");
    while (token != NULL) {
        printf("c = %d\n", c);
        printf("Token:\n%s\n", token);
        printf("Token addr:%p\n", &token);
        sscanf(token,
               "nodeId:%u nodeAddress:%s nodePort:%d",
               &ft[c].nodeId, ft[c].address, &ft[c].port);
        printf("id: %u\n", ft[c].nodeId);
        printf("addr: %s\n", ft[c].address);
        printf("port: %d\n", ft[c].port);
        token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
        printf("Token after:\n%s\n", token);
        printf("==========================\n");
        c++;
    }
    return c;
}
```

**The output is the following:**

```
answer at this point is:

nodeId:65228883 nodeAddress:127.0.0.1 nodePort:3081

nodeId:65228883 nodeAddress:127.0.0.1 nodePort:3081

nodeId:65228883 nodeAddress:127.0.0.1 nodePort:3081

nodeId:65228883 nodeAddress:127.0.0.1 nodePort:3081

nodeId:65228883 nodeAddress:127.0.0.1 nodePort:3081

c = 0

Token:

nodeId:65228883 nodeAddress:127.0.0.1 nodePort:3081

Token addr:0x7fff05bac308

id: 65228883

addr: 127.0.0.1

port: 3081

Token after:

nodeId:65228883 nodeAddress:127.0.0.1 nodePort:3081

==========================

c = 1

Token:

nodeId:65228883 nodeAddress:127.0.0.1 nodePort:3081

Token addr:0x7fff05bac308

id: 65228883

addr: (null)

port: 0

Token apres:

nodeId:65228883 nodeAddress:127.0.0.1 nodePort:3081

...
```

As you can see, the first line is correctly put into the struct, but from the 2nd iteration, even if the token is set to the next line and seems to have the correct content, only the first element of the struct is set (nodeId), but not the two others.

I believe my lack of understanding of strtok/sscanf may be involved here.

Thanks !

EDIT: here is a mvce. With that, even the first token is not parsed correctly by sscanf. This may have to be with the "%s" I'm trying to set with an ip address..

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char answer[8192] = "nodeId:107813116 nodeAddress:10.190.233.184 nodePort:3081\nnodeId:107813116 nodeAddress:10.190.233.184 nodePort:3081\nnodeId:107813116 nodeAddress:10.190.233.184 nodePort:3081\nnodeId:107813116 nodeAddress:10.190.233.184 nodePort:3081\nnodeId:107813116 nodeAddress:10.190.233.184 nodePort:3081";
    const char s[2] = "\n";
    char *token;

    typedef struct {
        char *address;
        int port;
        unsigned int nodeId;
    } node;

    node * ft = malloc(32 * sizeof(node));

    /* get the first token */
    token = strtok(answer, s);

    int c = 0;
    /* walk through other tokens */
    while (token != NULL) {
        printf("c = %d\n", c);
        printf("Token:\n%s\n", token);
        printf("Token addr:%p\n", &token);
        sscanf(token,
               "nodeId:%u nodeAddress:%s nodePort:%d",
               &ft[c].nodeId, ft[c].address, &ft[c].port);
        printf("id: %u\n", ft[c].nodeId);
        printf("addr: %s\n", ft[c].address);
        printf("port: %d\n", ft[c].port);
        token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
        printf("Token after:\n%s\n", token);                                                                                                                                                                       
        printf("==========================\n");
        c++;
   }   

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: Please show the declaration of `ft[]`

Comment: what would `printf("Token addr:%p\n", token);` print ?

Comment: @WeatherVane node *succFt    = malloc(32 * sizeof(node));

Comment: @dvhh well it prints the address pointed by token, so it seems legit that it doesn't change. Am I wrong?

Comment: This is not your real code. `request(addr, port, request, answer);` cannot compile as `request` is not a function. `ft` is never defined, etc. [The error could be in the code you have left out](http://ideone.com/RZeZPk). Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Bacon please show how you allocate memory for each `ft[c].address`  field which you are passing to `scanf()` to be filled.

Comment: @WeatherVane I actually just allocated memory when declaring ft, not for every field of the struct. This piece of code is what I'm compiling (request is a method that contact another service to fill out "answer") - so there is no hidden code there. Should I allocate memory for each ft.address field before the sscanf?

Comment: @n.m. I should be able to get a mvce, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You allocated memory for your `struct` array like this

```
node *ft = malloc(32 * sizeof(node));
```

but you have not initialised each `struct` element, every one of which has a pointer to a string which has not been allocated any memory. You then pass this uninitialised string pointer as the `%s` argument to `scanf()`, which will result in Undefined Behaviour. If you are lucky, it works when the string pointer *just happens* to point to memory you own that does not corrupt anything else.

I can't explain why `ft[1].port` was printed as `0` but you have edited the output, so it can't be trusted to be your *actual* output. (it says "apres" instead of "after").

Comment: I'm checking that right now. the "apres/after" thing was just a translation, not involving other modifications.